# Change FrameColor of Material UI Inputs on Reset btn

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui

i use Angular Material UI and in Registermenu when i click on reset-btn, the content is deleted but the red-frames is not back to the normal colors.
can anyone help me?
thank you.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U68mh.jpg)

register.component.html - reset-btn:

```
  <button
    mat-button
    type="button"
    (click)="onReset()"
    class="btn-block">Reset</button>
```

register.component.html - part of fields code:

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Benutzername</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      type="text"
      formControlName="username"
      [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f['username'].errors }" autocomplete="off">

    <mat-icon matSuffix>person</mat-icon>

    <div *ngIf="submitted && f['username'].errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f['username'].errors['required']">Benutzername ist erforderlich</div>
      <div *ngIf="f['username'].errors['minlength']">
        Der Benutzername muss mindestens 6 Zeichen lang sein.
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="f['username'].errors['maxlength']">
        Der Benutzername darf nicht länger als 20 Zeichen sein.
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside **onReset()** method, try to reset *submitted* variable to false:

```
this.submitted = false
```

Comment: i have it register.component.ts:

  onReset(): void {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.form.reset();
  }